# HTML CSS Table issue in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I've encountered a problem with the tables in IE 9/10/11. I've tested the following code using Firefox, Chrome and evil IE. On jsfiddle, jsbin everything works just fine in every browser. However, when I test this code on my HTTP server (tested on lighttpd and python SimpleHTTPServer) the table is displayed incorrectly:

[image: IE]

```js
var cell = $('#main tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(1);
cell.attr('class', 'block');
cell.css('height', '80');
cell.css('width', '40');
```

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tg td {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0;
}
.tg .block {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="main" class="tg">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a server issue then.  Use the developer tools and make sure all the resources are loading correctly

Comment: Can you provide a link to jsfiddle so we can see your HTML?

Comment: @photo_tom it's in the OP ...

Comment: Please dont escape the restrictions for adding jsfiddle links by putting the link itself in code tags - by including the relevant code in the question itself you wil elicit a better reponse. I've added on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be seen in IE-7 and below. The problem is caused by this:

```
<TD class=block style="HEIGHT: 80px; WIDTH: 40px" class="block"></TD>
```

Moreover, you have set `position:absolute` on this cell. The other browsers seem to be tolerant about this, but IE < 8 is tripping on this.

In order to achieve the look you are after, use `rowspan` and `colspan`, or an overlay.

Here is a correct cross-browser way:

```css
.tg {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.tg td {
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 0;
}
td.hilite {
    padding: 0;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="main" class="tg">
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td>
        <td></td><td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="4" class="hilite">h</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td>
        <td></td><td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td>
        <td></td><td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No it's not. The reason I use position absolute instead of rowspan/colspan is because I can preserve the correct frame of reference. Try to modify some cell by its index row:cell and see what's the point.

Comment: @Adam: That's ok. I cannot comment on your use-case, I merely pointed out where and why is your code tripping, especially in IE. This is visible in jsFiddle as well. IE is moving the cell out of flow and hence the hole. Now, its up to you if you want to support IE<8 or not.